# How to compare two strings in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

If I had something like `R11` and `R2`, I would expect `R2` to be less than `R11` but it’s not:

```
select 
    case when 'R11' < 'R2'
      then 'YES'
      else 'NO'
    end
```

Produces a `YES` when it should be no.

Is there a easier way to do this besides making a CLR function?

Comment: Why do you expect 'R11' to sort lower than 'R2'? Can you define your sorting criteria a little more precisely? And given that you seem to be storing information bundled up into a string, can you redesign your source data so the letters are in one column, and the numbers in another?

Comment: `R02` would be "less" than `R11`.  For this question, are you **always** comparing a string that has a letter followed by one or more digits?

Comment: That is a pretty quick jump to CLR. .NET will sort those two string values the same way.

Comment: WHat if you remove the first letter and then just compare two `INT`s? No CLR required.

Answer (score 1):

is this what your looking for, sorting numeric part of the string as int and character part as character. Hope this is helpful.

Considerations: Total length 5, 1'st character [a-z], 2-5 characters [0-9]

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), String VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @TestTable
VALUES('R1'),('R11'),('R12'),('R2'),('R21'),('Q12'),('U2'),('R21')

SELECT
    tt.ID,
    tt.String
FROM
    @TestTable tt
ORDER BY LEFT(tt.String,1),CAST(STUFF(tt.String,1,1,'') AS INT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alphanumeric sorting is not the same as natural sorting. If you want to avoid a CLR and if the input data is always in that format (`Rxxx`) then you can just remove the first letter and compare two `INT`s:

```
DECLARE @Index1 AS INT
DECLARE @Index2 AS INT

DECLARE @StrIndex1 AS VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @StrIndex2 AS VARCHAR(10)

SET @StrIndex1 = 'R11'
SET @StrIndex2 = 'R2'

SET @Index1 = CAST(RIGHT(@StrIndex1, LEN(@StrIndex1) - 1) AS INT)
SET @Index1 = CAST(RIGHT(@StrIndex2, LEN(@StrIndex2) - 1) AS INT)

SELECT 
    CASE when @Index1 < @Index2
      THEN 'YES'
      ELSE 'NO'
    END
```

Comment: This assumes the OP is **always** dealing with a string that has a single alpha character in position one.

Comment: @MaxVernon: Yes, I know (also mentioned it in the answer). I can adjust it once/if the OP answers.